# spooldir connector not processing large file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

there is large file with 40M records. the spool dir connector processed half of the records but after that it stopped pushing the records to the Topic. log is something like below -

```
 327878 [2021-01-07 23:08:59,903] INFO Processed 20060000 lines of /dir/dir1/abc.txt_1607697517821.txt (com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceTask:144)
 327879 [2021-01-07 23:08:59,997] INFO Processed 20080000 lines of /dir/dir1/abc.txt_1607697517821.txt (com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceTask:144)
 327880 [2021-01-07 23:09:00,225] INFO Processed 20100000 lines of /dir/dir1/abc.txt_1607697517821.txt (com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceTask:144)
 327881 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,788] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-1} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect        .runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
 327882 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,788] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-1} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset c        ommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
 327883 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,795] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-1} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 6 ms         (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:574)
 327884 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,795] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect        .runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
 327885 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,795] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset c        ommit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
 327886 [2021-01-07 23:09:04,795] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=cust-stream-2} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect        .runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
```

commit offset flush messages in last few lines are getting repeated in the log.

abc_1607697517821.txt.PROCESSING  file still exists , showing that it's not finished yet.

Comment: You can still use Connect FilePulse as an alternative to Spooldir if it doesn't match your need for processing large files:https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/